# Delete folders older then 1 day not working with "find" cmd

Tags: bash

I'm trying to delete backup folders older then 1 day (creation date) with find command, but it's not working

Folder ls -l:

```
drwxrws---+ 2 root data 42 Mai 15 16:46 15-05-2019
drwxrws---+ 2 root data 89 Mai 16 14:19 16-05-2019
```

The creation date is 15 Mai.

This cmd should work:

```
find /data/backup/VMs/centos/ -type d -mtime +1 -exec rm {} \;
```

I tried with this first to see what happens before the remove:

```
find /data/backup/VMs/centos/ -type d -mtime +1 -exec ls {} \; >> find_test.txt
```

It should write to the file the folder to delete, but the txt file is empty.

besides use find, how can I remove this folders using the date in the name?

Comment: UNIX doesn't store the creation date of files, looks like you meant modification date though. You don't show in your question what the date/time was when you ran your command so - have you taken into account from the man page `When find figures out
              how many 24-hour periods ago the file was last accessed, any
              fractional part is ignored, so to match -atime +1, a file has
              to have been accessed at least two days ago.` (same applies for mtime)?

Comment: Thank you for your help, do the date changes if I open the folder?

Comment: "folder" is a Windows term I believe, in UNIX there are directories and files. When you open (access) something you change it's access time, when you modify it you change it's modification time - both are available to you with `stat`, `find`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

`rm` normally doesn't print on standard output, however if an error occurs it prints to standard error which can also be redirected to another file or to the same duplicating the file descriptor `2>&1`

```
find /data/backup/VMs/centos/ -type d -mtime +1 -exec ls {} \; >> find_test.txt 2>&1
```

to print the name find `-print` action can be used, also find has actions `-delete` and `-ls` (which is not exactly the same than ls) to avoid to execute a command on each file

```
find /data/backup/VMs/centos/ -type d -mtime +1 -print -delete >> find_test.txt 2>&1
```

be careful before using `-delete` to avoid loosing unwanted files

Comment: There is another way to remove the folders by the date in the name?